# Mocks or Stubs?

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, stubs, mox

I have a method that calls two other methods in it.

```
def main_method(self, query):
  result = self.method_one(query)
  count = self.method_two(result)
  return count

def method_one(self, query):
  #Do some stuff based on results.
  #This method hits the database.
  return result

def method_two(self, result):
  #Do some stuff based on result.
  #This method also hits the database.
  return count
```

I'm not very experienced at unit testing and have never worked with Mocks and Stubs.

I'm not too sure how to create a unit test for my first method. Since method_one and method_two hit the database many times and they are very expensive, I have decided to use mox to create a mock or stub in order to eliminate the need of hitting database.

I would really appreciate it if someone who has experience working with Mocks and Stubs give me some hints on using mocks and stubs for my case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Before worrying about testing `main_method()`, first test the smaller methods. Consider `method_one()`. For the purpose of discussion, let's say it exists in a class like this:

```
class Foo(object):
    def method_one(self, query):
        # Big nasty query that hits the database really hard!!
        return query.all()
```

In order to test that method without hitting the database, we need an object that knows how to respond to the `all()` method. For example:

```
class MockQuery(object):
    def all(self):
        return [1,2]
```

Now we can test it:

```
f = Foo()
q = MockQuery()
assert f.method_one(q) == [1,2]
```

That's a basic illustration. The real world is often more complicated. In order to be worth the trouble of writing the test, your mock `all()` would likely do something more interesting than return a constant. Along similar lines, if `method_one()` contains a bunch of other logic, our `MockQuery` might need to be more elaborate -- that is, capable of responding appropriately to more methods. Often while trying to test code you realize that your original design was overburdened: you might need to refactor `method_one()` into smaller, more tightly defined -- and thus more testable -- parts.

Taking the same logic a step up in the hierarchy, you might create a `MockFoo` class that would know how to respond in simplified ways to `method_one()` and `method_two()`.